# Soft input keyboard is not hiding on edittext

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext, keyboard

I have created a project in which, I have a class that extends fragments, in which the frame layout consist two edit text. Problem here is whenever I click/touch on any edit text, the soft input keyboard popups which I don't want to popups. I tried the following method to disable the soft input keyboard.

In `androidmanifest.xml` file, I have also used the property `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`

```
public class Convert extends Fragment{ 

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.converter_data_layout, container, false);

        screen_v1 = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.data_value1);
        screen_v2 = (EditText) viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.data_value2);

        screen_v1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                hideKeyboard(getContext());
            }
        });

        screen_v2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                  hideKeyboard(getContext());
            }
        });

        return viewGroup;
    }

    public void hideKeyboard(Context context){
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        View view = ((Activity)context).getCurrentFocus();
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

My xml file code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="rahuldadoriya.mathsolver.convert.Convert"
    android:id="@+id/frame_data">
    <EditText
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:id="@+id/data_value1"
        style="@style/EdittextStyle"
        android:layout_weight="2.8"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:clickable="true"/>

    <EditText
        android:maxLength="15"
        android:id="@+id/data_value2"
        style="@style/EdittextStyle"
        android:layout_weight="2.8"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="25dp"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:clickable="true"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you register your keyboard in manifest file ?

Comment: Follow this tutorial here https://android.jlelse.eu/learn-to-create-a-system-keyboard-on-android-95aca21b1e5f And also this one https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for your help, I have solved my problem but not fully satisfied with the solution, because what i have used for not popping up the soft input keyboard is setting `setInputType(0)` for both the edittext, i.e.

```
screen_v1.setInputType(0);
```

similarly for the other edittext but the issues here is after using the above method on both the edittext, cursor is not visible on either of the edittext.
So if any one have any reason why it is happening so please help me.

Thanks

Comment: You can raise different issue for that.